# how to create document library in sharepoint 2010 using client object model

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-clientobject

i am struggling to create a document library in a site using sharepoint Client object model.

main idea is to create document library after that under each document library we will create sub documents.

Please let me know..

Thanks 
Kajal

Answer (score 0):

```
  ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("your Site goes here");
  Web rootWeb = clientContext.Web;
  //Get List
  var query = clientContext.LoadQuery(rootWeb.Lists.Where(p => p.Title == "SharedFolder"));
  clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
  List list = query.FirstOrDefault();
  string[] namesArray = new string[] {  "Folder1","Folder2"};
  foreach (string name in namesArray)
   {
    //Add Folder
    var folders = list.RootFolder.Folders;
    clientContext.Load(folders);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    var newFolder = folders.Add(name);
    Console.WriteLine(name);
  }
  //Execute request
  clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```